# Implementing SKReceiptRefreshRequest logic

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Maybe somebody can help me a bit with this. I am developing an app that includes auto-renewable inapp purchases and I am not sure about where to implement SKReceiptRefreshRequest.

My app triggers

```
[[IAPManager sharedManager] addTransactionObserver]
```

on AppDelegate to observe inapps (since I believe that being auto-renewable some transactions can occur when the app it's closed, like renews or cancellations.

Then I check subscriptions like that (on MainViewController)

```
bool receiptExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] path]];

if (receiptExist == NO) {

    if ([[UserManager sharedManager] isPremium] == true) {
        // Is't premium, but no receipt, launch receipt grab function here

        SKReceiptRefreshRequest *refresh = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
        refresh.delegate = self;
        [refresh start];
    }

    [[UserManager sharedManager] setIsPremium:false];
    [[UserManager sharedManager] saveUser];
    return;
}
else {
    // activate receipt check and enable features
}
```

Then after that I grab the receipt and check again subscriptions

```
- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request
{
    [[SubscriptionManager sharedManager] updateSubscriptions];
    [[SubscriptionManager sharedManager] updateEventsLog];
    NSLog(@"updated subscriptions");
}
```

Is this correct?

I have read that SKReceiptRefreshRequest should be called after completeTransaction or restoreTransaction event only, just for security reasons

Comment: I've did it almost the same way. But I still have some doubts - InAppPurchase process is quite complex .

If a user have purchased the item on another device, then the userDefaults have no 'Premium Version' key ( Unless Prefs are iCloud based… ).

Why not refresh the receipt in all cases? Can you tell me @alejandro-luengo ?

Comment: For that case I implemented restore purchases and it's working. I have not submitted for review, so I am not sure if it's ok 100%

Comment: Good luck then… ;) I'm also waiting for some validation after a long fight.
For user who install on a fresh device, they have to click manually on a restore button to re-enable their purchases. I hope it is the right way…